# Copy Rows from Sheet With Same Leading Cell Text

Tags: vba, excel

So I have been stumped by this for a while now. I have two sheets with some values in column 1 bolded. I wish to filter through the values on the second sheet (Mult. Year Set up) and copy the entire row of data with the same column 1 bolded Text.

[Page from Which data is to be coppied](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jzYPsQg--gNG5pS2dmWk5yMk0/view?usp=sharing)

[Page Which Data is to be coppied to](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jzYPsQg--gUzJJbE1lNko0aE0/view?usp=sharing)

For example I would like to take the "Backhoes" row from the first link and copy it to the "Backhoes" row on the Second link.

The major issue here is that the rows on the first page with bolded text are variable and may not allways have the same row number. The row numbers will change when more equipment is added.

Thanks in advance for the assistance, as I said, I have been working on this for a few days now.

Additionally, the data must be transposed from a row to a column, but that is a minor detail.

Comment: Your Page Which Data is to be coppied to is not shared.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jzYPsQg--gNG5pS2dmWk5yMk0/view?usp=sharing

Sorry Matthew, can you view if from this link?

Comment: Yes i can see that one.

Comment: It looks like we need to find the match on the target sheet and write to that row, right?   If so i will change the below example to that.

Comment: Well, I actually need to transpose the whole row to a verical format so that the column headers  matches up with the italicized row headers on the target sheet.

I was running into an issue becuse of the source sheet having variable row numberings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at something like this.
1. Loop through the rows looking for bold cells.
2. Loop through all the columns and copy the data from the source sheet to the target sheet.

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRowFind As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Year Budget")
Set targetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mult. Year Set up")

    lRow = 5
    Do While lRow <= sourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'You could do it by name
        'If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = "Backhoes" Or ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = "Graders" Then

        'If we are looking for variable rows by them being bold. We can do this.
        If sourceSheet.Range("A" & lRow).Font.Bold = True Then

            'Find the row on the target sheet where we want to write the data.
            lRowFind = 1
            Do While lRowFind <= targetSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
                If targetSheet.Range("A" & lRowFind).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A" & lRow).Value Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            lRowFind = lRowFind + 1
            Loop

            'Now we have a row that we want to copy.
            For iCol = 1 To sourceSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count
                targetSheet.Cells(lRowFind + iCol, 2).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(lRow, iCol).Value
            Next iCol
        End If


        lRow = lRow + 1
        sourceSheet.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your speedy resopnse. I should be able to work it out from there.

Comment: I made a change that should do it.  Changed targetSheet.Cells(lRow, iCol).Value  to  targetSheet.Cells(lRow + iCol, 2).Value  That should write them down in column B.  I can't test right now though.  Good luck.

Comment: And now i added the search for the row where the catagory (backhoe) actually starts.  That changes the target write line to    targetSheet.Cells(lRowFind + iCol, 2).Value.    Hope that helps too.